# different aligned pointers pointing to the same memory

Tags: c++11, memory-management, g++

This code returns always the same value for the double* pointers u and r. However, if I remove the attribute__((aligned(16))) it works correct. Is this usage of attribute_((algined(16))) invalid?

Edit: I'm using g++ 5.4.0 on ubuntu 16.04 (32bit)

```
int main(void){
double* __restrict __attribute__((aligned(16))) u=(double*)aligned_alloc(16,1252*2502*sizeof(double));
std::cerr<<"u after alloc: "<<u<<std::endl;
memset(u,0,1252*2502*sizeof(double));
std::cerr<<"u after memset: "<<u<<std::endl;
double* __restrict __attribute__((aligned(16)))r=(double*)aligned_alloc(16,1252*2502*sizeof(double));
std::cerr<<"r after alloc: "<<r<<std::endl;
memset(r,0,1252*2502*sizeof(double));
std::cerr<<"r after memset:"<<r<<std::endl<<std::endl;

}
```

Comment: [Can't reproduce](http://rextester.com/GFOMQL5421). I see distinct values for `u` and `r`.

Comment: When you use language extensions, you should mention which compiler you target, and preferably add tags accordingly.

Comment: Be sure the example will compile and run. This one lacks the necessary include-files. Tell what compiler you are using, and add a tag for that compiler.